# Change default shell to powershell in Neovim

Tags: neovim, shell, powershell

Currently the default shell nvim uses is `cmd.exe` I tried changing it by setting shell to powershell in my nvim config but that didn't work, so I tried this command in the nvim command line:

```
:let &shell = 'path/to/powershell.exe'
```

Echo shell command output the powershell path and when I executed `:terminal` it opened a `powershell` tab but after quitting and reopening nvim it was still using `cmd.exe`

How do I permanently change the default shell to powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permanently means puting it in your `_vimrc`. Open it (or create it if it doesn't exist yet) and add the line

```
set shell=path/to/powershell.exe
```

or maybe

```
let &shell = 'path/to/powershell.exe'
```

You may need to ajust some other parameters also: `shellcmdflag`, `shellquote`, `shellxquote`, `shellpipe`, `shellredir`, etc. For example, something like:

```
set shellcmdflag=-NoLogo\ -NoProfile\ -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned\ -Command\ [Console]::InputEncoding=[Console]::OutputEncoding=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8;
```

Comment: Maybe could copy the line to put in `_vimrc` to make the answer more clear?

Comment: Sorry, I though it was obvious (i.e. OP says "I know how to change the option, but I want it to remain permanently now" so i reply to put it in the rc where so that it will be loaded everytime) I'll update the answer as you've requested

Comment: Understandable :-) But I believe your new version will be more useful to others ;-)

Comment: Good catch: i forgot that many oter people would read later. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to a windows computer or powershell atm. Also my rep is too low to add this as a comment. But have you set everything mentioned in `:help shell-powershell`?

Also there is/was a issue with setting the default shell for neovim, see [the gh issue](https://github.com/akinsho/toggleterm.nvim/issues/90). If everything is set as in the help command and still no success then you could try the workaround posted in th gh issue.