# An unknown element "" was received / sending commands to Powershell

Tags: neovim

[image: bug]

This is what I get upon sending **ls** to powershell in Neovim. I have put `vim.opt.shell="powershell.exe"` in my init.lua file.

PS: it also happens when running the command `w !clip`.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: also the w !clip problem?

Comment: I only tried the first.

Comment: With the `w !clip` and the settings bellow I have a different error message (`Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do (from [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/39688/23502)):

```
set shell=powershell.exe
set shellxquote=
let &shellcmdflag = '-NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command '
let &shellquote   = ''
let &shellpipe    = '| Out-File -Encoding UTF8 %s'
let &shellredir   = '| Out-File -Encoding UTF8 %s'
```

Comment: is this proper lua?

Comment: I assume I have to wrap this in a vim.cmd function, right?

Comment: That this worth a try :-)

Comment: The settings are pure VimScript. You have to convert to Lua.

Answer (score 0):

-- Set up the shell to be powershell

```
vim.o.shell = 'powershell.exe'
vim.o.shellxquote = ''
vim.o.shellcmdflag = '-NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command '
vim.o.shellquote = ''
vim.o.shellpipe = '| Out-File -Encoding UTF8 %s'
vim.o.shellredir = '| Out-File -Encoding UTF8 %s'
```